# JS Uncaught TypeError: cannot read properties of undefined (vanilla js)

Tags: javascript, html, typeerror

im losing hair follicles over this =)

so i'm making the UI for a rock paper scissor page;
everything works fine, except for random weird console errors.

i have a logic function, a random computer Choice function, and an event listener.

i'm trying to make it so clicking an icon(svg) invokes the logic function to process who won.

it works fine, 50% of the time. i could not find a pattern at all for raising error. thanks in advance.

```
//rock paper scissor game..
//helper dictionaries for functions
const mapState = {0:"draw", 1:"win", 2:"loss"};
const mapChoices = {"rock":0, "paper":1, "scissor":2}

//function responible for computer choice
function randomizer() {
    let choices = ["rock", "paper", "scissor"];
    //chooses a random decimal from 0(inclusive) to 1(exclusive)
    randomDecimal = Math.random();
    //changes the random to 0/1/2
    randomChoice = Math.floor(randomDecimal*3);
    //finds the tool associated with the number choosen, and prints it.
    let computerChoice = choices[randomChoice];
    console.log(computerChoice);
    //return the random number (0/1/2)
    return randomChoice;
}

//game logic determining win, loss, draw.
function logic(humanInput, computerChoice) {
    
    const arrayMatrix = [[0, 2, 1],
                         [1, 0, 2],
                         [2, 1, 0]];
            let result = arrayMatrix[humanInput][computerChoice];
            console.log("logic result: " + result);
            return result;
    
    

}
//hardcoded game length
function roundsCount() {
    return 5;
}

//the DOM variables:
let tools = document.querySelectorAll(".tool");
let rock = document.querySelector("#rock");     
let paper = document.querySelector("#paper");
let scissor = document.querySelector("#scissor");
let divOutput = document.querySelector("#score");

function doRound(e){
    let humanChoice = mapChoices[e.target.id]
    let randomChoice = randomizer();
    let result = logic(humanChoice, randomChoice);
    console.log("doround result: " + result);
    return result;

}

divOutput.innerText = "Choose Your Weapon!"

tools.forEach(tool => {
    tool.addEventListener('mouseover', event => {
      tool.classList.add("selected");
    });
    tool.addEventListener('mouseout', event => {
        tool.classList.remove("selected");
      });
      tool.addEventListener('click', doRound);
  });
```

the browser determined the problem is with my logic() function, specifically in the `let result = arrayMatrix[humanChoice][coputerChoice]` part

my code: https://codepen.io/sirbecalo/pen/KKqggEO

feel free to add general advice/ improvements to my code, im a total newbie

Comment: `let result = arrayMatrix[humanChoice][coputerChoice]` - There's no such line in the script. Always post the correct/actual code... Either the _"the browser determined..."_ is not correct or the code. Both shouldn't be the case.

Comment: The error tells you that `arrayMatrix[humanInput]` results in `undefined` which means that `humanInput` is `>= arrayMatrix.length` (or maybe negative)

Comment: thank you tons, the code snippet you referenced is the first declared variable inside the logic function.

i understand what you say, but i reviewed that and as you can see, the top 2 dictionaries are how humanInput and ComputerChoice are converted to indexes, and they only can be 0/1/2, and the array is a 2d 3x3 matrix, so i am unsure how that would be an issue

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the help!
i figured the reason the error was invoked was due to the event target (click target) being a polygon INSIDE the SVG instead of the entire svg element.

this is observed by adding console.log(e.target) into my doRound() function.

now finding a way to "group" the svg in a way so clicking anywhere inside will trigger entire SVG element.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.